# Parse Dashboard is missing columns

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

[x ] You're running version >=2.1.4 of Parse Server.

[x ] You've searched through existing issues. Chances are that your issue has been reported or resolved before.
Environment Setup

Ubuntu DigitalOcean

Steps to reproduce

I have created a config.json file and I run

```
parse-dashboard --config config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1
```

The config file:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "http://ip/parse",
      "appId": "id",
      "masterKey": "key",
      "appName": "name"
    }
  ],
 "users": [
    {
      "user":"kwstasna",
      "pass":"something"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have installed parse-dashboard today and I have connected it with my iOS app that i develop now. So my app when is connected to the parse-server-example it makes the the right classes and columns. When I sign up a user with email it signs up correctly BUT when I go to my parse-dashboard there are no columns such as "username" "email" "password" and some others.

So I log out from this user and I try to login via Facebook (which was working great on the parse.com version)

Then I get an error

> Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values

I guess this happens cause it cant find the above columns.

When I tried to add "username" column manually nothing happened. I refreshed and somehow all the missing columns appeared.

I tried then to login via Facebook and everything worked grate.

Then I refreshed the dashboard and the columns disappeared again.

Also installation class doesn't have "badge" "devicetoken" "deviceType" "pushType" and many more.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you put the user's username, password, etc. on the server, add the columns in your parse-server dashboard. My guess is, when you send the into from the app to the server, the data will appear. I had the same problem with Parse.com where I had to add the column first or the data wouldn't show up in the data browser.